# Mysql Innodb Deadlock for not locked queries

Tags: java, mysql, innodb, deadlock, spring-jdbc

I have a strange situation, two identicaly conflicting queries (made by throw different application thread to the same record). The second one will fail with a DeadLock error.

The query is a very simple `UPDATE table SET unindexedColum=1 WHERE pk=X`

Checking the application and the inno status, the first (winning) query has a "S" lock, the second a "X" lock.
But application did not explicitly open that lock.

Is it possibile that a lock is made automatically by application or by InnoDB?

The application is a Java app with Spring - JDBC.

Comment: There are similar problems with Mariadb as well. I don't know the problem but at least there are several bugs regarding deadlock issue.

Comment: But you need to send logs of Mysql about deadlock.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=deadlock&status=Active&severity=&limit=10&order_by=&cmd=display&direction=ASC&os=0&phpver=&bug_age=0

Comment: Just to clarify: deadlock does not mean that there is a bug! The best way to debug deadlock issues is to obtain information as to what caused the deadlock by using innodb status monitor. Btw, update statement does set an X lock, but not an  S lock.

Comment: So in my case what can cause a `S` lock if my app doesnt have any kind of explicit lock?

Comment: Any type of implicit locking read acquires an `S` lock. For example `INSERT...SELECT...`, or `CREATE TABLE...SELECT...` or `UPDATE ... (SELECT...)` or `SET @variable = (SELECT...)` or `SELECT ... INTO...` or any use of `SELECT` inside a trigger. Basically any use of SELECT as part of a statement that saves or modifies data becomes a locking SELECT.

Comment: You might get more information from the deadlock section of the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` report.

Comment: Do you think it is possible an increment of deadlocks amount due to a missing index? I'm wondering if a missing index of an UPDATE WHERE condition can force a lock at table level causing an higher frequency of deadlocks.

Comment: Is the `UPDATE` a part of a transaction that involves more SQL statements than just that one statement?  Please locate and present the entire transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql handle lock row  himself no need to manage lock at row on application. Just manage transaction on application.

Depending of you innodb configuration
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

MySQL will handle locks on rows with different strategy, but default REPEATABLE READ.

Maybe you need to select the row you want to update with "select for update" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html in a transaction to be clean, and use exception in application side if there is a deadlock.